# Bring Set-Acl output to file

Tags: powershell, permissions

I have a PowerShell Problem:
My Script gives modify permissions to "user2" to a Folder with Get-Acl and Set Acl.
When I run Set-Acl, I want the standard output to be piped into the logfile. But when I look, the logfile is just empty.

My Code:

```
$permisions = Get-Acl D:\home\user1\Folder
$accessrule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule ("domain\user2","Modify","Allow")
$permissions.SetAccessrule($accessrule)
Set-Acl -AclObject $permissions -Path "D:\home\user1\Folder" -Verbose | out-file -FilePath $logfile -Append
```

I also tried with

```
Set-Acl -AclObject $permissions -Path "D:\home\user1\Folder" -Verbose >>$logfile
```

But both isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

Add the -Passthru parameter to the [Set-Acl cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849810.aspx).

> By default, Set-Acl does not generate any output. However, if you use
>   the Passthru parameter, it generates a security object. The type of
>   the security object depends on the type of the item.